# Can we simulate holes and start robot on a higher level (floor)?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm working on a robot navigation (on simulation) and I wanted to see if it is possible to:

1. add some holes on the ground on gazebo
2. start gazebo world with a robot on a higher ground to see how would it react to stairs going downwards

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328348/can-we-simulate-holes-and-start-robot-on-a-higher-level-(floor)?/) by [Syrine](https://answers.ros.org/users/41424/syrine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course. You can specify where to spawn your robot (full 3d pose) , and you can use the building editor in gazebo to create buildings with floors, steps, walls, doors, etc. Here is a link to the gazebo tutorial for it: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=building_editor

As far as creating holes in the ground, you'll have to create an sdf that can be loaded into gazebo that represents the terrain you want your robot to move around in. This sdf should be static. Just doing a quick search for "gazebo height map" I found a nice looking tutorial: https://github.com/AS4SR/general_info/wiki/Creating-Heightmaps-for-Gazebo

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Syrine](https://answers.ros.org/users/41424/syrine/) on 2019-07-23**:
Thank you! that's really helpful